# Change printing text size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file which contains a log report.  I want to print that report in a smaller text size.  I tried with below css style, but text size was not changed.  How to solve this.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Events</TITLE>

<STYLE type="text/css">
 table, th, td
 {
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   padding: 5px;
 }
</STYLE>

 <STYLE type="text/css" media="screen">
  #eventText { 
   display: block; overflow-y: auto; height: 600px; 
   width: auto; left: 0px; top: 50px; font-size: 0.25em;
  }
  #eventButtons { display: block; }
 </STYLE>

 <STYLE type="text/css" media="print">
body { margin: 0; background-image: none; font-size: 0.25em }
    #eventText { 
    display: block; 
    overflow-y: visible; 
    height: auto; 
    margin:0; 
    font-family: geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
        }
        #eventButtons { display: none; }
      </STYLE>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <div id="eventButtons">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="View" onclick="javascript:loadValues();">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Print" onclick="javascript:window.print();">
  </div>
  <div id="eventText"> </div>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: try putting that style to page(not only in print mode) and then look at your text with firebug or ie dev tools to see if some other class is not overwriting that font-size. Or just try to use `!important` and see what happens :-)

Comment: Works for me. What browser did you test with and what is the inherited font size you take 0.25 the size of? Maybe you're better off using a "physical" font size, like `5pt` or something.

Comment: have you some other style defined or loaded after that, with media="all" or with no media defined?

Comment: @MrLister i tried with ie 8 and firefox, but no change in result

Comment: @krish OK. Stupid question, but did the rest of the styles get applied? I mean, did the `eventButtons` disappear, etc?

Comment: @MrLister yes, div eventButtons disappear while printing

Comment: @krish The font size in your "print" block is the same as in your "screen" block, did you know that? And you have an error in your "screen" CSS (`600` instead of `600px`). And your `eventText` div is empty, so there's no text to print...

Comment: @krish By the way, is it me or does your source keep changing? Anyway, it's possible that your browser has a "minimum font size" setting (I know Firefox does) that prevents the font from shrinking below a certain minimum.

Comment: @MrLister yes you are right.  In my firefox font size is set at 16pt.  Can i override this setting by using css or other

Comment: No, you can't override that setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exact solution is to use @media rule in CSS

You can set the CSS to change the styles of elements when the web page tries to print. The following CSS will set the background color to white in all the DIV elements when printing.

```
@media print{    
    div{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

You can easily set the fonts of the elements of your choice this way although you can do much more with it.

You can find more about @media rules [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than declare `font-size:.25em` use an absolute value like `font-size:xx-small`.